# Canada visitor visa holder - do I also need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, canada, transit-visas

I hold a valid multiple-entry B1 visa for Canada, which I have used in the past for business related travel. I am planning a tourist visit to the United States soon, and would like to transit via a Canadian airport on my way back. Would I need to obtain a separate transit visa for this purpose, or can I use my currently valid B1 visa to transit Canada?

Comment: Does Canada have a "B1" visa type?  Searching just turns up the US B-1 visa type.

Comment: @NateEldredge Apparently they do, see e.g. *[Can I use B1 visa (Visitor-Business) to travel to the Canada without a business purpose?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/24340)*

Comment: Do you have a separate visa issued by Canada, or are you asking whether your US visa allows you also to enter Canada?

Comment: @choster but that's not what Canada calls its business visa, per Canadian user DJClayworth in your linked Q&A

Comment: If that's the case, we should correct it everywhere.

Comment: Huh, but Mandy's comment on DJClayworth's answer insists that they have that notation on a Canadian visa.

Comment: @NateEldredge but, like you, I can't find any such reference on the CN government site

Comment: @Dorothy can you find any indication on any government sites that there's such a thing as a V-1 visa or an S-1 visa?  Those certainly can be found in image searches, yet I'm also unable to find information about them on Canadian government sites.  The only list I found was on facebook, and it also mentions the B-1: https://www.facebook.com/StraightCanada/posts/303102789757928

Comment: My Canada visa sticker states "B-1, VISITOR-BUSINESS" under the "Category" field. I am talking about the Canadian visa of course (I have a separate B1/B2 visa for the US).

Comment: @phoog same as what I find, that non-gov lists as such, and [google images](https://international.viu.ca/sites/default/files/styles/max_size_cropped/public/canada-visa.jpg?itok=QVTMLwYF) do... we'll just have to ask the gov and OP may have answered the Q as he a separate visa for CN, correct?

Comment: @Dorothy the question concerns a Canadian B-1 visa  What do you mean by a "separate" visa for Canada?

Comment: @phoog just trying to clarify that OP has two visas, one for CN and the US visa, as the B-1 in reference to both was confusing as stated.

Comment: @Dorothy it's not clear whether the "tourist visit" mentioned in the question would be on a visa or the VWP.

Comment: @phoog to your knowledge, would a CN B1 business visa allow entry for transit/connecting flights (as a US B1/B2 would)?

Comment: @Dorothy I do not know, but the UK also allows transits on visitor visas, so I guess Canada probably does, too.

Answer (score 1):

[Immigration in Canada](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/business-info.asp) clarifies that:

> There is no separate application for business visitors. The temporary resident visa covers all visitors, including those in Canada on business.
>
> If your business partners or contacts are likely to visit Canada a number of times, they may want a multiple entry visa. This means they will not have to request a visa every time they want to enter Canada. Multiple entry visas are granted whenever possible.

Such a visa allows you to board a flight that will connect to an onward international destination in Canada. Depending on your flight connections, you may not even need to enter Canada, and [transit without visa can be accomplished at certain Canadian airports](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/authorities.asp), and particularly when you hold a US visa and onward tickets to an international destination.

> The Transit Without Visa (TWOV) program allows eligible foreign nationals to transit through Canada without a visa or an eTA. At present, the TWOV program operates at the Vancouver International Airport in British Columbia, Canada, the Calgary International Airport in Alberta, Canada, and Toronto's Pearson International Airport (Terminal 1 only) in Ontario, Canada.